# Subspace of $\mathbf{R}^n$ is compact if and only if closed and bounded proof

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm trying to understand this proof in my topology section. Specifically, the direction showing compact implies closed and bounded:

> Suppose $A$ is a compact subspace of $\mathbf{R}^n$. Since
>   $\mathbf{R}^n$ is Hausdorff, we know $A$ must be closed.

I understand that part.

> Since $A \subset \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} K_i^n$ where $K_i = (-i,i)$, and since
>   $K_i^n \subset K_j^n$ for $i \le j$, there exists an integer $i_0$
>   such that $A \subset K_{i_0}^n$ and thus $A$ is bounded.

What allows us to conclude that there exists an integer $i_0$ such that $A \subset K_{i_0}^n$? Is this due to the Tychonoff theorem stating that Cartesian products are compact if and only if their component spaces are? Even then, the conclusion doesn't seem immediate.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\cup_{i=1}^\infty K_i^n$ is an open cover of $A$. Hence, by compactness, there is a finite subcover, say for $i=j_1, \ldots, j_k$, where without loss of generality $j_1<j_2<\cdots<j_k$.

The property $K_i^n\subset K_j^n$ then ensures $A\subset K_{j_k}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $K_i^n$ form an open cover for $A$, there exists a finite set $\{i_1,i_2\dots, i_k\}$ such that $$A\subset K_{i_1}\cup \cdots K_{i_k}$$

Now, define $i_0=\max\{i_1,i_2,\dots, i_k\}$ and you have $K_{i_1}\cup \cdots K_{i_k}=K_{i_0}$ so the inclusion follows.

---

The fact that $K_{i_0}=K_{i_1}\cup \cdots K_{i_k}$ follows from the fact that for each $i_m$, you have $i_m\leq i_0$ and therefore $K_{i_m}\subseteq K_{i_0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Our aim is showing that $A \subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$ compact is a subset of $K_{i}^n=(-i,i)^n$ for some enough large $i \in \mathbf{N}$.

We consider the family of open sets $\{K^n_j\}_{j \in \mathbf{N}}$. We have $A \subseteq \mathbf{R}^n \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} K_i^n$  and since we know $A$ is compact we can cover $A$ by only a finite number of sets of that family:  $A \subseteq \cup_{j=1}^{i_0} K_j^n$.

But $\{K_j^n\}^{i_0}_{j=1}$ is an increasing sequence of nested boxes, so $\cup_{j=1}^{i_0} K_j^n=K^n_{i_0}$ and we have the aim.